# If vs Filter in RxJS Performance Comparison

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Consider an example with **RxJS.**

**Type A: [using filter]**

```
this.userService.afAuth.authState
      .pipe(filter(user => !!user))
      .subscribe( _ => this.router.navigate(["/anything"]) )
```

**Type B: [using if]**

```
this.userService.afAuth.authState
      .subscribe( user => {
        if(!!user) this.router.navigate(["/anything"])
       })
```

> **Q1.** How do we compare the performance?
>
> **Q2.** Which is recommended and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q1**. How do we compare the performance?

You can use https://jsperf.com/ to create your performance test. I can tell you that "Type B" must perform better because there are less function calls involved. This will only be noticable if you call the function **really** often (maybe at 10.000 calls / second as a rough estimate). For typical use cases, there won't be a difference.

> **Q2**. Which is recommended and why?

From a design point-of-view, "Type A" is recommended. It features a more declarative syntax and is thus easier to replace or reuse. As an example, your `filter` pipe could be extracted into a reusable pipe and used multiple times. If your predicate changes at some point, you only have to change it once.

Comment: Thanks for your viewPoint. It looks quite promising.